# Trying to get the correct delta time

Tags: c++, sdl, timedelta

I am trying to create a simple game in SDL and I am currently stuck on delta time. Here's the main loop:

```
bool quit = false;
DeltaClock deltaclock;

// ...

while ( !quit ) {

    while ( SDL_PollEvent(&evt) != 0 ) {
        quit = evt.type == SDL_QUIT;
        // handle the input
    }

    double delta = deltaclock.tick();

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    world.update(delta);
    world.render();

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_Delay(1000/60 - delta);

}

// ...
```

and this is the DeltaClock class:

```
class DeltaClock {

public:

    DeltaClock() {
        curr = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();
        last = 0;
    }

    double tick() {
        last = curr;
        curr = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();

        return ((curr - last) * 1000 / static_cast<double>(SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency()));
    }

private:

    Uint64 curr;
    Uint64 last;

};
```

The problem is when I print the value of delta I get values like: 600, 1200, 1900, 150, 500, etc. At first I though I am doing something wrong inside world.update() or world.render() that slows down the game, so I took them out. However, I was still getting high delta time values. Is anything wrong with the logic of calculating the delta time? Am I missing something there?

**EDIT:** Removing the call to `SDL_Delay()` doens't fix the problem.

Comment: what is your expected output? AFAIM delta is the diff between curr and last and the sequence of delta values does not have to follow a specific pattern.

Comment: @GhasemNaddaf I don't mind for "specific pattern" but 1900 delta time means the frame needed 1.9s. So, my expected output is lower values.

Comment: I see, can you, for the sake of debugging, cout example values of `last` and `cur`? Does `SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency()` always return the same value?

Comment: I don't see anything particularly wrong here. Are you saying it isn't your actual framerate (should be fairly noticable with so huge time difference)? Can you post complete compilable example illustrating your problem? What is your OS / SDL render driver?

Comment: @keltar "Are you saying it isn't your actual framerate" exactly. I mean 1900 delta time means about 0.5fps. Still let's say my game slow down the loop. Even if I completely remove calls to `.update()` and `.render()` I still get high delta values. I can post the rest of the main.cpp but there's not much just decelerations and init of sdl stuff. Everything happens inside `GameWorld` object. My OS is Windows. What you mean by SDL render driver?

Comment: @DimChtz better reduce it to minimal program that fits single block of code. By video driver I mean https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetCurrentVideoDriver , but I suppose it is d3d for you as SDL defaults to that on windows.